# Additional recipients on woocommerce invoice

Tags: woocommerce

Is there way to add additional recipients to woocommerce invoice mail.
I have tried to use 'woocommerce_email_headers' hook, but it's not working:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'mycustom_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);

function mycustom_headers_filter_function($headers, $object) {
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Bcc: My Name <me@gmail.com>';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html';
    return $headers;
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You can expand the function to include the order as well:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'woo_cc_emails', 10, 3 );

function woo_cc_emails( $headers, $status, $object ) {
    return 'Bcc: your@email.here' . "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: could you explain how can I use this to add more than one address to the BCC field please?

Comment: The following should work: `return 'Bcc: your@email.here, another@email.com, and@another.com' . "\r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Some months later, but I hope this will help someone.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_headers', 'woo_cc_emails');
function woo_cc_emails() {
  return 'Bcc: your@email.here' . "\r\n";
}
```

You can change "Bcc", with "To" or "Cc".

Answer (score 0):

I needed help to add a BCC to a New Customer Account email. Here is what I came up with. It's slightly different than above. Hope this helps someone.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_bcc_to_wc_customer_new_account', 10, 3 );
function add_bcc_to_wc_customer_new_account( $headers = '', $id = '', $wc_email = array() ) {
if ( $id == 'customer_new_account' ) {
    $headers .= "Bcc: my_personal@email.com\r\n"; // replace my_personal@email.com with your email
}
return $headers;
}
```